# Google Maps not showing on android v2.2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building an application which has its major functionality on google maps. But the problem I am facing in one of the device is that:

The Google Maps never load on that device [its OS is Android v2.2]

I have checked for the Google Play Service and it always gives a dialog to update the Google Play service; but when I click ok it redirects me to the play store where it shows that i already have the google play library [No update option there]

I connected the device and checked the logcat which states something like this:

**"Current Google Play Service Version is 35xxx and required is 41xxx"**

but there is No way for me to update the google play service as it never shows the update option. Please help me with this issue.

Give me all possible solution that i should try out... I need this app working on android 2.2.

*I am using google maps api v2. Also Note the app is working fine on all other android versions.*

Thanks.

**USING Google Maps v1 can SOLVE MY PROBLEM....?? Please Help!**

Comment: 2.2 is outdated any reason why you are still supporting this ?

Comment: @user88975 so that means you don't support any lower version but only latest i.e. 4.4 ?

Comment: Most devs have dropped support for 2.2-  lots of APIs don't work on it anymore, and its less than 2% of the install base.  Unless its an absolute necessity it isn't worth the effort.  Usually they support back to 2.3, which is still 20% of the market

Comment: Breakdown of percentage of users for each version by OS version  http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net

Comment: My Client needs it, he is ready to deploy a separate apk for android 2.2 and 2.3 [with limited functionality], but he wants to support them  at any cost..

Comment: @PareshMayani I didnt mean that. Check Gabe's inputs for reasons.

Comment: Yes i am aware of the 2.2 being outdated...but i still need to struggle to find a way out..... using an older google maps version will help me???????????? as in google maps v1...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use older version of Google Maps Android API v2.

The latest supported on 2.2 devices is 3.2.65 (v12) and can be downloaded via SDK Manager.
Just look for Google Play services for Froyo.

Or if you are using Android Studio and Gradle, make your dependency version equal to 3.2.65.

Comment: Thank you sir! I will try this out and post back my output. Thankz again!